# What is the default value (after server installation) of the dbms_scheduler default_timezone attribute

Tags: oracle, timezone, dbms-scheduler

Does anyone know what is the default value for the default_timezone attribute of the dbms_scheduler? That is, without this value ever being set manually.

For example, on one of my servers, the following statement returns the value '`Europe/Vienna`'.

```sql
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.get_scheduler_attribute('default_timezone', :VALUE);
END;
/
```

while `/usr/bin/timedatectl` on the server returns

```
      Local time: Do 2023-03-30 13:27:28 CEST
  Universal time: Do 2023-03-30 11:27:28 UTC
        RTC time: Do 2023-03-30 11:27:27
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
     NTP enabled: n/a
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
                  So 2023-03-26 01:59:59 CET
                  So 2023-03-26 03:00:00 CEST
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
                  So 2023-10-29 02:59:59 CEST
                  So 2023-10-29 02:00:00 CET
```

I did not find anything regarding this in the Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DBMS_SCHEDULER Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-73622B78-EFF4-4D06-92F5-E358AB2D58F3):

> - The calendaring syntax does not allow you to specify a time zone. Instead the Scheduler retrieves the time zone from the `start_date` argument. If jobs must follow daylight savings adjustments, then you must specify a region name for the time zone of the `start_date`. For example specifying the `start_date` time zone as 'US/Eastern' in New York ensures that daylight saving adjustments are automatically applied. If instead, the time zone of the `start_date` is set to an absolute offset, such as '-5:00', then daylight savings adjustments are not followed and your job execution is off by an hour for half the year.
> - When `start_date` is `NULL`, the Scheduler determines the time zone for the repeat interval as follows:
>
> 1. It checks whether or not the session time zone is a region name. The session time zone can be set by either:
>
>    - Issuing an `ALTER SESSION` statement, for example:
>
>      ```
>      SQL> ALTER SESSION SET time_zone = 'Asia/Shanghai';
>      ```
>    - Setting the `ORA_SDTZ` environment variable.
> 2. If the session time zone is an absolute offset instead of a region name, the Scheduler uses the value of the `DEFAULT_TIMEZONE` Scheduler attribute. For more information, see the `SET_SCHEDULER_ATTRIBUTE` Procedure.
> 3. If the `DEFAULT_TIMEZONE` attribute is `NULL`, the Scheduler uses the time zone of `systimestamp` when the job or window is enabled.

Comment: And where does this part of the documentation tells me what the default value of `DEFAULT_TIMEZONE` is?

Comment: The last item: "If the DEFAULT_TIMEZONE attribute is NULL ..." i.e. there is no default value for `DEFAULT_TIMEZONE`

Comment: No, it just tells me, if the attribute is NULL, it uses `systimestamp`. Where does it says NULL is the default?